# Making unlisted data look like before making it to a table

Tags: excel, vba, datatables

I have a data set attached to my task. During making a task I organize it to a table, but now I want to make makr to remove the table and make it looks like before doing a task. I know the command:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTable").Unlist
```

But it still left the cells colorized and when I try to delete the color with

```
Range("A1:B51").Interior.Color = xlNone
```

It left the range colored white without the lines between cells.
I will be greatfull for any ideas how to make it look like before the task. Thanks

Comment: Make a copy of the original data, do all the calculations then delete the copy. Original data stays the same, even just duplicate then delete the sheet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range("A1:B51").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone`

Comment: Thank You, and do You know how to not delate a columns headers when unlisting the data?

Comment: The headers were not deleted, they are only written in white on white. You can use `Range("A1:B51").Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic` to fix that.